# XSLT: Passing Excel text color parameter to templates

Tags: excel, xslt, xslt-1.0

This one has left me completely confused. I have a multi text color cell. Most of the data is shared in one way or another so I wanted to use templates to do most of work. To do that I sought to pass the text color as a parameter to the template. A super simple example:

```
<xsl:variable name="textColor">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$cellColor = 's73'">
            <xsl:text>#FFFFFF</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>#000000</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:call-template name="detailLines">
    <xsl:with-param name="textColor" select="$textColor"/>
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="detailLines">
    <xsl:param name="textColor"/>
    <!-- Start new line -->
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- Bunch of stuff after this -->
    <Font html:Color="{$textColor}">
        <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
    </Font>
```

Usually I have no issues out of this, but I was floored when the text color didn't seem to pass. However, when I debug the text color is passing. Further investigation showed that the XML created has the text color as well, but Excel does not display it, but instead defaults to black.

I've got the Excel namespaces in their usual location and even attempting to move them around doesn't help resolve the issue.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
            xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Any ideas would be great! I've not had an issue quite like this where the variable is acting as expected, but Excel is not.

EDIT TO ADD ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

I've found a difference, but I'm not sure how to interpret it.

```
<Font html:Color="#FFFFFF">Two Box</Font>
<Font html:Color="#FFFFFF">]</Font>
<Font html:Color="#FFFFFF" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">[</Font>
```

The first two lines are from code that does not enter the detailLines template and so it calls the cellColor variable directly. The last line is from the template where the variable is passed. The namespace seems to be causing my issue, but I can't understand 1) why it is there, and 2) how to make it go away.

EDIT - Addressing cellColor comment

I cannot put the actual code here for multiple reasons, but the cellColor variable is calculated just prior to the textColor. At it's most redacted it is:

```
    <xsl:variable name="cellColor">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="A">
                <xsl:text>s216</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="B'">
                <xsl:text>s73</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>s210</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
```

Comment: how are you computing $cellColor? any xslt code would be helpful.

Comment: Also can you show your transformed xml output to understand why excel cannot display the color.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. First, we need to know what the result of the transformation **should** be in order for Excel to display it correctly. Find out (say here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx) and add that to your question. Then provide a **reproducible** example of the transformation (incl. any input being used), so that we can fix that and make it output the aforementioned expected result. See: [mcve]

Comment: @Jason H I am almost sure you are using just plain xml to be displayed in the excel which is fine as far as you don't have to assign styles to the cells. If you want styles to the cells in excel like color, bold text, you certainly need a Workbook/Worksheet in your xsl and Cell's with styles defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as can be determined by myself as well as commenter Peter Vande Weyer there is no way to pass the text color in the manner I am attempting. The issue occurs because the template where this color formatting is located is not the main template so the xslt processor is applying the namespace. This application of the namespace causes Excel to fail as it is not expected in the location that the processor inserts it. The only solution at this juncture is to not use a separate template when handling this text formatting.

Answer (score 1):

A cell with different colored letters in is looks like this in spreadsheetML

`<Cell>
    <ss:Data ss:Type="String" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
        <Font html:Color="#000000">tes</Font>
        <Font html:Color="#9BC2E6">t</Font>
    </ss:Data>
</Cell>`

Comment: I am no expert on SpreadsheetML, but this doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you want to assign value to a variable in xsl, you should use `<xsl:value-of select=`

Change your cellColor variable assignment to :

```
<xsl:variable name="cellColor">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="A">
                <xsl:value-of select="'s216'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="B'">
                <xsl:value-of select="'s216'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="'s210'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
```

and the textColor variable to :

```
<xsl:variable name="textColor">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$cellColor = 's73'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'#FFFFFF'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'#000000'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

About how to make it go away for the xmlns, you can just remove it.

Comment: No, this makes no difference. You can certainly use `xsl:text` to output literal text. Or just the literal text. The result will be exactly the same.