# Excel not displaying text when html:color applied via XSLT

Tags: excel, xslt

Many moons ago I asked (and answered) a question about passing text colors as a parameter of a template in XSLT for Excel (See:[Passing Excel text color parameter to templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36992747/xslt-passing-excel-text-color-parameter-to-templates))
and at first I thought this was related because I had the Data portion in a template, but since the text color is hard coded this time that wasn't at play. Just to be sure made a super simplistic test case. Maybe I'm just too tired to see the simple solution.

I have a cell with two sets of text. If a check variable passes, then I want to write the second part of text in red, while leaving the first part always in white.

My simplistic XSLT test case is below. What I would expect in this setup is to see "Période Du 01-01-2019 Au 31-01-2019" in white text and " Aucun Mois Fiscal Sélectionné" in red text. If the French bothers you for any reason just switch the English variable to Y (Love writing bi-lingual reports!).

More maddening to me is that in the SpreadsheetML I see the desired result, it just isn't displaying in Excel itself. Instead Excel just displays a blank cell.

XSLT Test Case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" indent="no"/>

<xsl:variable name="english" select="'N'"/>
<xsl:variable name="selectedDates" select="'N'"/>
<xsl:variable name="reportPeriodStart" select="'01-01-2019'"/>
<xsl:variable name="reportPeriodEnd" select="'31-01-2019'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Workbook>
        <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
            <Author>Developer</Author>
            <Created>2018-12-11T17:43:39Z</Created>
            <Version>16.00</Version>
        </DocumentProperties>
        <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
            <AllowPNG/>
        </OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
            <WindowHeight>8712</WindowHeight>
            <WindowWidth>23040</WindowWidth>
            <WindowTopX>32767</WindowTopX>
            <WindowTopY>32767</WindowTopY>
            <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
            <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
        </ExcelWorkbook>
        <Styles>
            <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
                <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
                <Borders/>
                <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
                <Interior/>
                <NumberFormat/>
                <Protection/>
            </Style>
            <Style ss:ID="s43">
                <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
                <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Bold="1"/>
                <Interior ss:Color="#005C96" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
            </Style>
        </Styles>
        <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
            <Table>
                <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="500"/>
                <Row>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s43">
                        <Data ss:Type="String" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
                            <B>
                                <Font html:Color="FFFFFF">
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="$english = 'Y'">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Period of ', $reportPeriodStart, ' To ', $reportPeriodEnd)"/>                                                    
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Période Du ', $reportPeriodStart, ' Au ', $reportPeriodEnd)"/>        
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </Font>
                                <xsl:if test="$selectedDates = 'N'">
                                    <Font html:Color="FF0000">
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="$english = 'Y'"> No Fiscal Month Selected</xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise> Aucun Mois Fiscal Sélectionné</xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </Font>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </B>
                        </Data>
                    </Cell>
                </Row>
            </Table>
            <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
                <PageSetup>
                    <Layout x:Orientation="Landscape"/>
                    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.5" x:Left="0.25" x:Right="0.25" x:Top="0.5"/>
                </PageSetup>
                <FitToPage/>
                <Print>
                    <FitHeight>0</FitHeight>
                    <ValidPrinterInfo/>
                    <Scale>89</Scale>
                    <HorizontalResolution>600</HorizontalResolution>
                    <VerticalResolution>600</VerticalResolution>
                </Print>
                <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
                <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
            </WorksheetOptions>
        </Worksheet>
    </Workbook>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: **1.** I don't see what this has to do with XSLT. If the transformation produces the expected result, and you still have a problem, then the problem is with Excel, not XSLT. -- **2.** I don't see any mention of `html:Color` in the XML Spreadsheet Reference. And I said the same thing on your previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked question actually has the answer for this (peter vande weyer's answer shows the correct format)

Your problem is with this element

```
 <Data ss:Type="String" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

By using a default namespace declaration here you are also putting the `Data` element in that namespace. `Data` needs to be in the `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet` namespace. As this is already bound to prefix `ss`, you just need to declare it like this:

```
<ss:Data ss:Type="String" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

Additionally, the font colours need to have the `#` prefix...

```
<Font html:Color="#FFFFFF">
```

So, your table element should look this this

```
<Table>
    <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="500"/>
    <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s43">
            <ss:Data ss:Type="String" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
                <B>
                    <Font html:Color="#FFFFFF">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$english = 'Y'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat('Period of ', $reportPeriodStart, ' To ', $reportPeriodEnd)"/>                                                    
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat('Période Du ', $reportPeriodStart, ' Au ', $reportPeriodEnd)"/>        
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </Font>
                    <xsl:if test="$selectedDates = 'N'">
                        <Font html:Color="#FF0000">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$english = 'Y'"> No Fiscal Month Selected</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise> Aucun Mois Fiscal Sélectionné</xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </Font>
                    </xsl:if>
                </B>
            </ss:Data>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
</Table>
```

Note, you will see you still have a problem with it not showing a line break, but you may need to ask another question for that if you can't work it out

Comment: Thank you. This was one of those "can't see the forest for the trees" moments.